# JHipster : Blob / ImageBlob / VideoBlob / AudioBlob datatype

Tags: image, audio, video, types, jhipster

JDL-Studio recognizes "ImageBlob" as a predefined datatype.

[image]

By importing the JDL file an entity class with a byte-array attribute will be created as well as a front-end component to browse an image file and also some components to display the image.

It's not the same with Video. I mean if you use "VideoBlob" it still creates the byte-array attribute and also a front-end component to browse and upload the video file but there is no way you can watch or download the video unless you handle it manually I guess.

I guess the same problem applies to audio type.

[image]

Would you please let me know what is your preferred solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VideoBlob and AudioBlob do not exist in JDL or the main JHipster generator, just ImageBlob and Blob.  JDL defaults to the Blob type when the field type ends in "Blob", as described in [the JDL documenation](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#blobdeclaration).

You will need to write the frontend manually.  You can do something similar to how ImageBlob works by using the data URI and specifying the content type in the `src` attribute.

Audio:

```
<audio controls="" src="data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAA...8l3KcK"></audio>
```

Video:

```
<video controls>
        <source type="video/webm" src="data:video/webm;base64,AAAAA...9tYXZAAAGnRm9/l/L+X8v5AAAAMgfDg==">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAHGe...XBtcDQyAAAAAGnRm9/l/L+X8v5AAAAMgfDg==">
</video>
```

Depending on the size of the audio/video files, it may be recommended to upload to a CDN which allows playing media by requesting byte ranges.  In JHipster's implementation, the full blob has to be downloaded before it can start playing.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try not use Blob datatype to storage big elements in database, I recommend that you use a static content server to upload audio/video and files of big size, this increase your system performance.

Comment: Do you have good examples of file uploading to static content server? Would be nice, if you share it.